# Need help for C++ boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

```
#include </usr/include/boost/optional.hpp>  
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


boost::optional<int> test_func(int i)
{    
  if(i)   
    return boost::optional<int>(1234);
  else   
    return boost::optional<int>();
  return (i);   
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  test_func(1234);
  std::cout<< test_func(i) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Could any body please tell me y am i getting the value of i as 0, what i want to do is i want to print the values of " i " after entering into " if " condition & also in the " else" part.

Please do the needful, refer me any modification's
Thanks 
Arun.D

Help is greatly appreciated.. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please format your source code to make it readable?

Comment: @Dan, already did so, just waiting for someone to approve the edit :)

Answer (score 4):

`int i` has not been explicitly initialised.  If `i == 0` then nil (default boost::optional) is returned, when you print you will get 0.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized `i`. The behavior of this program is undefined. Set it to a non-zero value explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

In main() you haven't initialized `i`. And in `test_func()` you will never reach `return (i);`.

Comment: if(i)   
    retun boost::optional<int>(1234);  But why atleast this is not returning the value. What i want to do is i want to simulate the functionality of Boost::Optional

Comment: if(i)   
    retun boost::optional<int>(1234);  But why atleast this is not returning the value. What i want to do is i want to simulate the operation of Boost::Optional pls help

Answer (score 1):

Other have already commented: you are using i without initializing and it is default initialized to 0.
But maybe you are wondering why you don't see 1234: this is because you are discarding the return value (hard-coded to boost::optional(1234) ).
Maybe you meant to write

```
std::cout << *test_func(1234) << endl; // by using operator* you are not discarding the return value any more
std::cout<< test_func(i) << endl;
```

Read [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/development.html#boost_optional.development.the_interface) and look at the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html) for more information

Comment: std::cout << test_func(1234) << endl;  with this now its printing only 1, can u please modify my code snippet posted above.. it would be great help, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the unitialized `i` and not reaching `return i;` other already mentioned:

You are printing the [bool conversion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/detailed_semantics.html#reference_optional_operator_bool) of `boost::optional`. When the optional contains a value it prints `1`, when the optional does not contain a value it prints `0`.

I think you mean something like:

```
boost::optional<int> result(test_func(i));
if (result)
{
    std::cout << *result;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "*not set*";
}
```

and not

```
std::cout << test_func(i);
```